# H1 pushing DIV content down issue

Tags: html, css

So first off, I know I can just do a quick `position:absolute` on the `H1` in this scenario and solve my issue. What I'm looking for is explanation as to WHY the below scenario occurs, and another more fluid way around it that doesn't involve `position:absolute`

Stripped down simple example of the behavior : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aorkzso/5/)

The H1 in the inner div seems to pad the entire cell and pushes the buttons on the right down. If I pull off the `<h1>` and just use a `<strong>` or something else it's fine. You'll see I have margin and padding set to 0

I'd appreciate learning a new trick while I'm knocking the dust off my css. Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer it's a quick fix :)

Comment: Oh, and a down-vote without an explanation is pretty useless to an OP. So thanks for those. it's a valid SO question though IMO.

Comment: on the a-grid-cell you will have to do some box sizing though.

display: inline-table;
vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a [table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).
The `h1` element cell and the buttons cell are on the same row, so they are displayed on the same line, one after the other. But I had not realized it was the vertical alignment that bothered you.

If you want to improve your skills, check [the flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know! It makes sense.

Comment: Oh and I'm using flex but I couldn't seem to lose the gutter margins and admittedly shot for something more familiar since I've been doing xaml for so long and not css.

Comment: It depends of what you want to achieve, but the table layout is not helping to make really fluid displays. Like old web pages built with <table>.

Comment: Yea I know, I'm brushing off the rust though and obviously need to dig deeper into flex to accomplish the goals.

Comment: Even without speaking of flexboxes, there is simpler ways to do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/gael/6aorkzso/9/

Answer (score 3):

In this way it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/6aorkzso/6/

```
<div class="a-grid">
    <div class="a-grid-row">
        <div class="a-grid-cell">
            <h1 id="zot">Blah Blah Blah</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="a-grid-cell">
            <div class="a-grid-container">
                <div class="a-grid-row">
                    <button>1</button>
                </div>
                <div class="a-grid-row">
                    <button>2</button>
                </div>
                <div class="a-grid-row">
                    <button>3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a-grid-container {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.a-grid-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.a-grid-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    border: #f00 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
}
#zot {
    background-color: #cf0;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I added a `background-color`, to see the boundaries of the `h1`, and a `vertical-align: top`.

Comment: Cool thanks, it's another way to do it but I was hoping for an explanation also.

Comment: Notice, in your code, the bottom of the `h1` aligned with the bottom of the first button. Being `h1` higher than the button, it pushes down the baseline.